# SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Object Error

Tags: sql, smo

When I try to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 Instance using Management Studio 2008 R2 with the valid credentials, I get "Bad IL Range (Microsot.SQLServer.SMO)" error.
However I can access server using SQLCMD succesfully and see that there is no problem with the database.
What do you think the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a good chance this error is caused by a virus that has corrupted your SQL Server installation, or at least some component SQL Server is relying on.  If you have the same issue I had, unwinding it may not be easy either.  This is because standard uninstall fails with the same "Bad IL range.." error, and even after using command line "msiexec /x" options to remove the related GUIDs, reinstallation fails with the same error.

[image: SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error: Bad IL range]

I'd be very interested to hear how someone else got around this issue, but I think a complete Windows reinstallation may be in order, and that would be my answer, painful though it may be.  I came to that conclusion after also looking into other suggested causes including fully uninstalling and reinstalling all .NET components after some answers pointed to corrupted .NET assemblies as being a potential cause.  Make sure you back up your databases prior to wiping the system and just reattach them after your get your installation working again.  Good luck!